# How to prepare parents for B2 VISA interview?

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas

I am living in USA with H1B VISA. My parents are in India. We ave applied B2 VISA for my parents and scheduled Interview. However my mother is not educated and my father is went to only high school. For them the names of cities, employers are worked are very new and they can not pronounce properly. And they don’t know all the visa related process and stuff also not proper. And also they use more dialects, slang and words which is very local to our native place and not a kind of text book language.

At this situation, I am little skeptical about their success in the VISA interview. How can I best prepare them for the VISA interview and what are the best tips and advices that I can give them?

Comment: They won't be the first, I imagine embassy employees face this on daily basis, nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 3):

There are fortunately lots of people who have written careful advice on the matter online.  I'll link to a few and then summarise. Exmaples:

- [Visitors Visa Interview Tips](http://www.immihelp.com/visitor-visa/visitors-visa-interview-preparation-tips.html)
- [Visa Interview Questions for B2 Visa](http://visainterview.info/us/visa-interview-questions-for-usa-visitor-b2-visa/)
- [Visitor Visa Interview Preparation](http://www.path2usa.com/visitor-visa-guide/visitor-visa-interview-preparation)

What it comes down to is being prepared.  Really prepared. This comes under a few categories:

- **Documents** - bring copies of all relevant documents, in case they are needed to refer to.  You'll look organised. Make sure you know what's in them, what they mean, and can find them easily in your collection of paperwork.  Make sure NOTHING is missing - missing paperwork is one of the main causes of visa refusal.  You should also know exactly where each document is - index them if you find that easier.  You don't want them to be shuffling papers around while the irritated official waits for them to find that old piece of information.
- **Questions** - this is going to be the hardest part for them. They could be asked anything (relevant to the application) but you can look at common questions (second link above) and practice them. Make sure you have the documents for the questions - eg if there's a question like 'what funds will you use to support yourself' - they should be able to produce bank account statements from their paperwork.
- **Intepreter** - note  that it is possible to ask in advance for an intepreter, if you feel that would help them if it's easier to use a family language.
- **Extra** - three rules. Do not argue. Do not ask unnecessary questions (that can lead to problems), and be polite, no matter what.  And if they don't understand or misheard a question, it's entirely appropriate to ask the interviewer to please repeat it more slowly/clearly.

Good luck!

Comment: Definitely do not argue (clarify if needed, but do not argue). A couple I know almost got their visa refused b/c one of them is a lawyer and didn't like some of the questions.